# How do I configure SQL Profiler to show me queries to the views sys.databases and sys.tables?

Tags: sql-server, trace

I have a simple C# app that iterates through all databases on a server examining their schema. As such it performs a `SELECT name from sys.database`, iterated through those and does a `SELECT name from sys.tables WHERE name='Something'`. Then if it finds the table its looking for it does some queries, and does stuff with the data.

The connection string has an application name. If I setup a trace with a column filter on that application name looking for start/complete transaction, start/complete stored procedure, and complete statement. I see the queries I perform on the actual database tables, but not the queries to sys.databases and sys.tables.

Comment: The book "Mastering SQL Server Profiler" by Brad McGehee can answer your questions on profiler. The PDF download is free. http://www.red-gate.com/community/books/mastering-sql-server-profiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing inherent in Profiler that would prevent those queries from being displayed. I think you're just not catching the right events. It sounds like you're filtering for Stored Procedure events. Try also filtering for TSQL events.

Comment: Yes I'm going with it was a PEBKAC error.